# How do I perform CRUD operations without Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on the front-end for a Ruby on Rails API, creating a page that shows documentation. I am using Postgres database with the application PSQL to hold the text data for the documentation, then loading it into the views via a controller, as typical Rails applications do.

Right now, I am trying to get the templates to look good with dummy data and am typing text data into the database using the Rails console, but this is horribly inefficient. Are there any ways to load data into Postgres without the console?

I have looked through ways to do this and the only lead I have is to use scaffolding, but I could not find a way to get Rails generators to update or add data to a database.

I would appreciate any recommendations for how to solve this problem and/or links to helpful resources.

Answer (score 1):

You could try seeding the database.

Here's a link to the docs on migrations and seeding:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data

The example from the docs shows this seed file:

```
5.times do |i|
  Product.create(name: "Product ##{i}", description: "A product.")
end
```

which load 5 products with an incrementing product number as seed data.
Basically, the idea is that you create the necessary objects in your seed file and run `rake db:seed`

Another way would be to put the data you want to insert into a migration and run `rake db:migrate`

Here's a link to a great post on database seeding:
https://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2013/04/25/rake-db-seed-in-rails/